# System.ArgumentException: The 'http://somenamespace.com/2012/10/' namespace is not defined

Tags: c#, wcf, web-services, soap

I have set a consistent namespace (http://somenamespace.com/2012/10/) to all of the following:

1. Service Contract namespace
2. Service namespace
3. Data Contract namespace
4. Binding namespace

However I'm getting this error on the service log (.svclog) files. Can someone enlighten me on this? I've already consulted several sites but to no avail.

Here's a good reference: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wcf/thread/ee11d86f-f25c-4284-8f51-b1f035346cb3/

```
<E2ETraceEvent xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/06/E2ETraceEvent">
<System xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/06/windows/eventlog/system">
<EventID>131074</EventID>
<Type>3</Type>
<SubType Name="Error">0</SubType>
<Level>2</Level>
<TimeCreated SystemTime="2013-01-04T06:57:48.7620812Z" />
<Source Name="System.ServiceModel" />
<Correlation ActivityID="{eadc96c2-323f-41df-bc3d-df56367dda52}" />
<Execution ProcessName="w3wp" ProcessID="2088" ThreadID="54" />
<Channel />
<Computer>SOMECOMPUTER007</Computer>
</System>
<ApplicationData>
<TraceData>
<DataItem>
<TraceRecord xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/10/E2ETraceEvent/TraceRecord" Severity="Error">
<TraceIdentifier>http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/System.ServiceModel.Diagnostics.EventLog.aspx</TraceIdentifier>
<Description>Wrote to the EventLog.</Description>
<AppDomain>/LM/W3SVC/1/ROOT/SomeApplication-1-130017541311895789</AppDomain>
<ExtendedData xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2006/08/ServiceModel/DictionaryTraceRecord">
<CategoryID.Name>EventLogCategory</CategoryID.Name>
<CategoryID.Value>7</CategoryID.Value>
<InstanceID.Name>EventId</InstanceID.Name>
<InstanceID.Value>3221356549</InstanceID.Value>
<Value0>System.ArgumentException: The 'http://somenamespace.com/2012/10/' namespace is not defined.
   at System.Xml.XmlWriter.WriteQualifiedName(String localName, String ns)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlWriterDelegator.WriteAttributeQualifiedName(String attrPrefix, XmlDictionaryString attrName, XmlDictionaryString attrNs, XmlDictionaryString name, XmlDictionaryString ns)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext.WriteTypeInfo(XmlWriterDelegator writer, XmlDictionaryString dataContractName, XmlDictionaryString dataContractNamespace)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext.WriteTypeInfo(XmlWriterDelegator writer, DataContract contract, DataContract declaredContract)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext.SerializeWithXsiType(XmlWriterDelegator xmlWriter, Object obj, RuntimeTypeHandle objectTypeHandle, Type objectType, Int32 declaredTypeID, RuntimeTypeHandle declaredTypeHandle, Type declaredType)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext.InternalSerialize(XmlWriterDelegator xmlWriter, Object obj, Boolean isDeclaredType, Boolean writeXsiType, Int32 declaredTypeID, RuntimeTypeHandle declaredTypeHandle)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext.InternalSerializeReference(XmlWriterDelegator xmlWriter, Object obj, Boolean isDeclaredType, Boolean writeXsiType, Int32 declaredTypeID, RuntimeTypeHandle declaredTypeHandle)
   at WriteArrayOfPaymentTypeBaseToXml(XmlWriterDelegator , Object , XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext , CollectionDataContract )
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.CollectionDataContract.WriteXmlValue(XmlWriterDelegator xmlWriter, Object obj, XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext context)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext.SerializeAndVerifyType(DataContract dataContract, XmlWriterDelegator xmlWriter, Object obj, Boolean verifyKnownType, RuntimeTypeHandle declaredTypeHandle, Type declaredType)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext.SerializeWithXsiType(XmlWriterDelegator xmlWriter, Object obj, RuntimeTypeHandle objectTypeHandle, Type objectType, Int32 declaredTypeID, RuntimeTypeHandle declaredTypeHandle, Type declaredType)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext.InternalSerialize(XmlWriterDelegator xmlWriter, Object obj, Boolean isDeclaredType, Boolean writeXsiType, Int32 declaredTypeID, RuntimeTypeHandle declaredTypeHandle)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext.InternalSerializeReference(XmlWriterDelegator xmlWriter, Object obj, Boolean isDeclaredType, Boolean writeXsiType, Int32 declaredTypeID, RuntimeTypeHandle declaredTypeHandle)
   at WriteMerchantCountryToXml(XmlWriterDelegator , Object , XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext , ClassDataContract )
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.ClassDataContract.WriteXmlValue(XmlWriterDelegator xmlWriter, Object obj, XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext context)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext.InternalSerialize(XmlWriterDelegator xmlWriter, Object obj, Boolean isDeclaredType, Boolean writeXsiType, Int32 declaredTypeID, RuntimeTypeHandle declaredTypeHandle)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext.InternalSerializeReference(XmlWriterDelegator xmlWriter, Object obj, Boolean isDeclaredType, Boolean writeXsiType, Int32 declaredTypeID, RuntimeTypeHandle declaredTypeHandle)
   at WriteArrayOfMerchantCountryToXml(XmlWriterDelegator , Object , XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext , CollectionDataContract )
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.CollectionDataContract.WriteXmlValue(XmlWriterDelegator xmlWriter, Object obj, XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext context)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext.SerializeAndVerifyType(DataContract dataContract, XmlWriterDelegator xmlWriter, Object obj, Boolean verifyKnownType, RuntimeTypeHandle declaredTypeHandle, Type declaredType)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext.SerializeWithXsiType(XmlWriterDelegator xmlWriter, Object obj, RuntimeTypeHandle objectTypeHandle, Type objectType, Int32 declaredTypeID, RuntimeTypeHandle declaredTypeHandle, Type declaredType)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext.InternalSerialize(XmlWriterDelegator xmlWriter, Object obj, Boolean isDeclaredType, Boolean writeXsiType, Int32 declaredTypeID, RuntimeTypeHandle declaredTypeHandle)
   at WriteMerchantExtendedToXml(XmlWriterDelegator , Object , XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext , ClassDataContract )
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.ClassDataContract.WriteXmlValue(XmlWriterDelegator xmlWriter, Object obj, XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext context)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractSerializer.InternalWriteObjectContent(XmlWriterDelegator writer, Object graph, DataContractResolver dataContractResolver)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractSerializer.InternalWriteObject(XmlWriterDelegator writer, Object graph, DataContractResolver dataContractResolver)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializer.WriteObjectHandleExceptions(XmlWriterDelegator writer, Object graph, DataContractResolver dataContractResolver)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializer.WriteObject(XmlDictionaryWriter writer, Object graph)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DataContractSerializerOperationFormatter.SerializeParameterPart(XmlDictionaryWriter writer, PartInfo part, Object graph)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DataContractSerializerOperationFormatter.SerializeParameter(XmlDictionaryWriter writer, PartInfo part, Object graph)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DataContractSerializerOperationFormatter.SerializeBody(XmlDictionaryWriter writer, MessageVersion version, String action, MessageDescription messageDescription, Object returnValue, Object[] parameters, Boolean isRequest)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.OperationFormatter.OperationFormatterMessage.OperationFormatterBodyWriter.OnWriteBodyContents(XmlDictionaryWriter writer)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.Message.ToString(XmlDictionaryWriter writer)
   at System.ServiceModel.Diagnostics.MessageLogTraceRecord.WriteTo(XmlWriter writer)
   at System.ServiceModel.Diagnostics.MessageLogger.LogInternal(MessageLogTraceRecord record)
   at System.ServiceModel.Diagnostics.MessageLogger.LogMessageImpl(Message&amp; message, XmlReader reader, MessageLoggingSource source)
   at System.ServiceModel.Diagnostics.MessageLogger.LogMessage(Message&amp; message, XmlReader reader, MessageLoggingSource source)</Value0>
</ExtendedData>
</TraceRecord>
</DataItem>
</TraceData>
</ApplicationData>
</E2ETraceEvent>
```

Comment: Not sure it will help a lot, but it seems to be related to the PaymentTypeBase class.

Answer (score 5):

Judging by the stack trace, I suspect you've got a derived class somewhere in your contract, particularly around PaymentType, PaymentTypeBase.

Try decorating your top level DataContract with the [KnownType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730167.aspx) attribute. This could help the deserializer to know what type to deserialize the response to.

Answer (score 0):

You may have just opened the can of worms of : "dealing with OO principals" but "working with Services".

Somewhere, you have to "pay the fiddler" about which Concrete of your abstract class you are going to actually use, aka, that gets passes across the service-wire.

Here is one approach: (this one uses reflection to figure out the concretes)

http://ashgeek.blogspot.com/2011/02/wcf-serialization-dynamically-add.html

Here is another: (this one uses a little text file to list out the concretes)

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wcf/thread/6b70e9f4-52bc-4fa9-a0ff-c0859e041e85/

In the end:
Services like concretes, and they don't like abstract classes or interfaces.

The poopty doop is that we've been told for years to program to interfaces (or abstract classes) and not to concrete implementations.